# Как получить цвет пикселя на холсте в Ткинтер?

Tags: python, tkinter

Пишу в данный момент программу для рисования мышкой, навроде Paint. Решил реализовать инструмент "Пипетка" для захвата цвета с экрана, то есть по нажатию на правую кнопку мыши цвет кисти меняется на цвет пикселя холста, на который пришёлся клик. Что я пытался сделать:
У меня есть окно верхнего уровня для рисования, назовём его newwindow, размер которого задан заранее и не меняется во время работы, в этом окне есть холст, назовём его canvas. Рисование происходит через newwindow.bind("B1-Motion", Paint), где Paint это функция самого рисования, расписывать её долго поэтому просто расскажу принцип, у нас есть две точки, настоящая и предыдущая, которые задаются через координаты соответственно (x1; y1), (x2; y2). То есть первая точка как бы тянет за собой вторую. На каждом шаге, то есть при каждом изменении координат мыши, первой точке присваиваются текущие координаты мыши, а вторая точка запоминает старые координаты первой точки, после чего методом create_line() между ними рисуется линия. Массив отрисованных элементов нигде не сохраняется. Для реализации пипетки мне потребовался newwindow.bind("Button-3", GetColor), где GetColor это соответственно метод для получения цвета суть которого я сейчас изложу. За цвет кисти в моей программе отвечает переменная color, которой в данной функции должно присваиваться новое значение color = canvas.itemcget(canvas.find_overlapping(event.x - 0.5, event.y-0.5, event.x + 0.5, event.y + 0.5)), данный фрагмент кода по идее должен возвращать цвет элемента, который накрыт квадратом 1х1 пиксель по местоположению мыши. Но либо я что то упустил, либо так оно работать не должно, в общем возвращает данный код пустую строку. Как исправить эту неприятность?

Comment: find_overlapping возвращает tuple из нуля или более элементов - id попадающих в указанный прямоугольник объектов. Если ни один не попадает, то будет пустой кортеж. Если попадает 1, то по идее нужно взять его по индексу 0 (а не брать весь tuple). Тут для объектов с обводкой вопрос, что считать цветом - цвет фона или цвет обводки. Если несколько объектов поверх друг друга, то нужно еще определить, какой из них самый верхний (теоретически это может быть последний элемент, но не факт).

Comment: Также вероятно find_overlapping не умеет работать с дробными координатами, поэтому попробуйте задать прямоугольник просто `canvas.find_overlapping(event.x, event.y, event.x + 1, event.y + 1)`

Comment: Я попробовал, но выдаёт ещё до  кучи ошибку, itemcget() missing 1 required positional argument: 'option'. Но я не представляю, за что этот аргумент отвечает. Искал в интернетах, но по данной тематике только аглицкие сайты, но и на них информация неполная. Возникает вопрос: Что писать на место 'option'.

Comment: option - название свойства (в виде строки), которое нужно получить. Если нужно получить заливку фигуры (или цвет линии), то `"fill"`, если цвет обводки фигуры - то `"outline"`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!